# matlab: addition of symbolic matrices along an unused dimension

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

How can symbolic matrices collected in a cell array be summed along an unused dimension? Assume, for reasons beyond the scope of this post, that the matrices must be the elements of a cell array, rather than planes of a higher-dimensional matrix. What follows is a brief demonstration of the problem.

Suppose we have a cell array of 2D `sym` vectors prepared as follows:

```
a = vpa(ones(2,2));
c = {a; 2*a; 3*a};
```

Despite the fact that it is possible to make multidimensional symbolic matrices with newer versions of matlab (e.g., `sym('c', [2 2 2])`), addition of 2D `sym` matrices along a third dimension fails

```
sum(cat(3, c{:}), 3)
    Error using symengine
    Arguments must be 2-dimensional.
```

With numeric inputs, the operation is successful:

```
a = ones(2,2);
c = {a; 2*a; 3*a};
sum(cat(3,c{:}), 3)
    6    6
    6    6
```

Edit:

In fact, the problem of multidimensional addition is more general than I had thought: `sum` cannot be applied to any `sym` matrix of dimensionality greater than 2.

```
a=vpa(ones(2,2));
sum(a,1)
    [ 2.0, 2.0]
sum(a,2)
     2.0
     2.0
a = vpa(ones(2,2,2));
sum(a,1) % fails
sum(a,2) % fails
sum(a,3) % fails
```

Manual addition of planes along a third dimension works, so iterative addition is an option, though `sum` would be preferable:

```
a=vpa(ones(2,2,2));
plus(a(:,:,1), a(:,:,2))
    [ 2.0, 2.0]
    [ 2.0, 2.0]
```

Edit #2:

According to [this page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symbolic-summation.html), the problem is apparently unavoidable since support for dimensionality >2 is explicitly not offered.

> Unlike the MATLAB® sum, the symbolic sum function does not work on multidimensional arrays. For details, follow the MATLAB sum page.

Nevertheless, suggestions on alternatives are still welcome.

Comment: I would just use a loop, and not look back. Symbolic matrices are slow to work with anyway, I wouldn’t worry about the negligible overhead of a loop.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Thanks, I appreciate the recommendation.